# PropertiesLauncher ignores -Dloader.path=

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring-boot 1.3.5/OS X/java 8.

The situation is as follows: I need to pass the Launcher a class folder that will trigger the devtools restarts. This folder is not known until execution.

I am passing -Dloader.path=/Users/..../class_folder. When I try to create an XML application context I get a FnotF exception. "Beans.xml" is there.

I have tried -Dloader.path=file:/Users... and -Dloader.path=file://Users...

I was thinking about modifying the Launcher source to use one of the command line args as the last classpath entry.

But it seems a little bit overboard if the functionality is already there.

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I remember the file protocol should in form of `file:///User...`. Am I wrong? And what is your full command? Have you ever tried `--loader.path=xxx`?

Comment: I will give it a try. According to other posts the "file" prefix is not necessary

Comment: Yes you are right. They are two different ways. But if you prefix with file it should be file protocol format.

Comment: Hello! It does not make a difference. I still get the FnotF. I will try -Dloader.debug=true to see if it dumps what the problem is

Comment: It seems to have no effect. I am debugging inside eclipse so I have no clue what the final command line is. I am passing the -D args in the vm arguments textfield

Comment: I mean how you start your application, `mvn  spring-boot` for example.

Comment: It is inside eclipse. Eclipse does not say what the final command line is. I used -- and I also moved the arg outside the vm args. No luck. Will continue .

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing is correct or not. But appendix from spring boot might be helpful. Example is too long, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your configured is correct or not. But reference from spring boot might be helpful.

```
# ----------------------------------------
# DEVTOOLS PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------

# DEVTOOLS (DevToolsProperties)
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true # Enable a livereload.com compatible server.
spring.devtools.livereload.port=35729 # Server port.
spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude= # Additional patterns that should be excluded from triggering a full restart.
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths= # Additional paths to watch for changes.
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true # Enable automatic restart.
spring.devtools.restart.exclude=META-INF/maven/**,META-INF/resources/**,resources/**,static/**,public/**,templates/**,**/*Test.class,**/*Tests.class,git.properties # Patterns that should be excluded from triggering a full restart.
spring.devtools.restart.poll-interval=1000 # Amount of time (in milliseconds) to wait between polling for classpath changes.
spring.devtools.restart.quiet-period=400 # Amount of quiet time (in milliseconds) required without any classpath changes before a restart is triggered.
spring.devtools.restart.trigger-file= # Name of a specific file that when changed will trigger the restart check. If not specified any classpath file change will trigger the restart.
```

So, I think you should specify for property `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths` instead of `loader.path`.

Please have a try and let know no matter it works or not.

---

Please add `layout` to your `spring-boot-maven-plugin` configuration as following if you do not already add it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <layout>DIR</layout>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the detail properties are listed here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features.

From this point, I think you can make it.

Comment: The problem seems to be the eclipse configuration. running maven install produces the correct manifest.mf and jar but if I look into maven dependencies PropertiesLauncher is nowhere to be found. Eclipse can not find it as main class in the debug configurations.  I will start there

Comment: One last update: eclipse is pretty much useless to debug spring-boot apps. The PropertiesLauncher is generated dynamically (it is in the executable jar but not in boot-loader-tools jar) so debugging the  maven project inside eclipse does not make any sense because it blindly starts the class that is supposed to be processed by a Launcher.  So I will use jdb and probably it will work as expected

Comment: The crux of the problem is that last class folder needs to be added to the spring-boot classpath so the restart picks the fresh classes. Unless additional-paths adds it at boot time

Comment: I am way past that. The problem is the configuration inside eclipse. maven install produces the correct jar and manifest but eclipse does NOT have the launcher in the class path so it debugs the main class directly without Launcher preprocessing

Comment: It could be. You can try Spring Tools Suite, which developed based on Eclipse. By the way, I can debug everything in IntellijIDEA, maybe you want to try. And if you manually create the MANIFEST.MF and specify PropertiesLauncher may could solve this problem.

Comment: For what it is worth: STS also ignores -Dloader.path=... I have used ZIP and  DIR as layouts. It seems that the Launcher is hard coded deep inside the ide. The solution seems to be using jdb and the executable jar. The Launcher in the jar does not have source attached to it so I will have to grab  the source from github and stuff it inside jdb. Thanks a lot for your help!!